# Getting a file name from directory in Lua

Tags: lua

I need to get the file name from a directory in a Lua.

I don't want to use `require "lfs"`.

Using popen / open would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for. Do you want to get the list of files in a directory?

Answer (score 4):

See [this entry on lua-list](http://lua-list.2524044.n2.nabble.com/Portably-iterate-over-a-directory-td4089759.html)

Specifically the following can be modified to do what you want:

```
local dircmd = "find . -type f -print" -- default to Unix
if string.sub(package.config,1,1) == '\\' then
        -- Windows
        dircmd = "dir /b/s"
end

os.execute(dircmd .. " > zzfiles")

local luafiles = {}
for f in io.lines("zzfiles") do
        if f:sub(-4) == ".lua" then
                luafiles[#luafiles+1] = f
        end
end

print(table.concat(luafiles, "\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the shell function in [the lua wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ShellAccess). As a command (c) pass a "ls /path/*pattern*" (assuming you are in unix or have cygwin installed if running windows).