# Loop through all the files in a directory with Corona and Lua

Tags: file, filesystems, lua, coronasdk

Is it possible in Corona SDK to get a list of all the files in a directory?
Say I have variable `resourceDir = system.ResourceDirectory`, how would I loop through all the files in resourceDir?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585571/need-to-get-a-file-name-from-directory-in-lua

Comment: You might want to read :http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/system-os as if you are developing for Android there is not a resource directory as such.

Answer (score 5):

This functionality has just been added with Corona including the [LuaFileSystem](http://keplerproject.github.com/luafilesystem/manual.html#reference) module:

```
local lfs = require "lfs"

local doc_path = system.pathForFile( "", system.DocumentsDirectory )

for file in lfs.dir(doc_path) do
    -- file is the current file or directory name
    print( "Found file: " .. file )
end
```

More info: 
http://blog.anscamobile.com/2012/05/luafilesystem-lfs-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Currently Corona doesn't support getting a list of files in a directory. There was a hack that used os.excute to issue a "ls" command but it turns out that only works in the Corona Simulator because the device OS is probably blocking the feature for security reasons.